# ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> \relax

Tags: hyperref

I've been working on my dissertation in LaTex Texshop for sometime and this morning I revived these error messages. I think it is somehow related to hyperref because when I disable this package the document parses fine but then I don't have the hyper ref ability... Help.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
! Extra \endcsname.
\check@bm@number ...0\else \csname B_#1\endcsname 
                                                  \fi 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
(./TEO-2013_Fall-Dissertation-jdm.out)
! Argument of \@@BOOKMARK has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@@BOOKMARK was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.131 \begin{document}

? 
! Extra \fi.
\@begindocumenthook ...apper {\ReadBookmarks }\fi 
                                                  \Hy@pdfstringtrue \PDF@Set...
l.131 \begin{document}
```

I am working with a template for the dissertation with several chapters. Here is my the basics of my file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}        
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper}                  
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{metre}
\usepackage{tone}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{utdiss2-05}         
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vowel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd} 
\usepackage{verbatim}       % Allows quoting source with commands.
\usepackage{makeidx}        % Package to make an index.
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{url}        % Allows good typesetting of web URLs.
\usepackage{draftcopy}      % Uncomment this line to have 
\newcommand{\latexe}{{\LaTeX\kern.125em2%
                      \lower.5ex\hbox{$\varepsilon$}}}
\newcommand{\amslatex}{\AmS-\LaTeX{}}
\chardef\bslash=`\\ % \bslash makes a backslash (in tt fonts)
\newcommand{\cn}[1]{\texttt{\bslash #1}}
\makeatletter       
\def\square{\RIfM@\bgroup\else$\bgroup\aftergroup$\fi
  \vcenter{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\@height.6em\kern.6em\vrule}%
                                              \hrule}\egroup}
\makeatother
\makeindex    % Make the index
\begin{document}

\copyrightpage       % Produces the copyright page.

\commcertpage       % Produces the Committee Certification
            %   of Approved Version page (doctoral)
            %   or Signature page (masters).
            %       20 Mar 2002 cwm

\titlepage              % Produces the title page.

\begin{dedication}
\index{Dedication@\emph{Dedication}}%

\end{dedication}


\tableofcontents  
\listoftables   
\listoffigures

\include{chapter-1-}

\include{chapter-2-}

\include{chapter-3-} 

\include{chapter-4-}

\include{chapter-5-}

\include{chapter-6-}

\include{chapter-7-}

\include{chapter-8-}

\include{chapter-9-}

\include{chapter-10-}


%\appendices
%index{Appendices@\emph{Appendices}}%

%\include{chapter-appendix1}

%\include{chapter-appendix2}

%\include{chapter-appendix3}


\begin{singlespacing}

%\renewcommand
%\bibname{References}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
%\bibliographystyle{language}  % Here the bibliography           %
%\bibliography{diss}        % is inserted.               %
%\index{References@\emph{References}}%  
\bibliographystyle{language}
\bibliography{jdm1-diss}
\end{singlespacing}


\printindex%    

\begin{vita}
\end{vita}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. -- One can not say where the error starts without a document

Comment: Will do. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just use another code block below or after the error message block

Comment: There are a lot of issues which breaks this example..`utdiss2-05.sty` is not available, leading to errors concerning `\copyrightpage`, `dedication` and `vita`, and all of the included chapters are not at hand. Commenting all of them out, the document compiles, but with an warning about the outdated `movie15` package

Comment: I cannot say what is going wrong with your code. I suspect either one of the included chapters or a wrong usage of one of the `utdiss2-05` package commands

Comment: Thanks  Christian.  I also suspect the same. It was when I was working on chapter 5.  Later I got an error saying that I had an extra } inserted somewhere. I think that is the case with this chapter.... Appreciate your time and help!

Comment: You could `%` the chapter 5 and see if it runs after that.

Comment: Yes. I tried that and there still seems to be a problem. In fact I % the last three chapters I was making revisions on and none of them proved to make any difference.This leads me to think that there is something wrong with the template for UTdiss.

Comment: I obtained a copy of that `utdiss2-05.sty` file and uncommented in your example the lines connected to that code. There were no errors. I assume, that the faulty code is in one of your `\include{chapter-*}` files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the source of the problem too. I will be carefully editing the chapter that I think is the culprit tomorrow. If I find the error I'll be sure to let you know. Thanks again for your continued checking on this problem. Much appreciated!